# How to query a recursive table avoiding registers father and children in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

Hi there Let's assume that I've got a recursive table like this:

```
ID Name Father_ID
1   A      --
2   B      1
3   C      2
4   D      2
5   E      4
6   F      1
7   G      6
8   H      1
```

For example, I do not need the registers with ID equal to 2 or 6, but I do not need either the registers where they are Father_ID. The register with ID = 5 is not taking into account because its father is 4, but at the same time 4 has as a father_ID the number 2. (Like a deep search). This will be the final result.

```
ID  Name   Father_ID 
1   A      --
8   H      1
```

What could be a good approach for performing this?

(This is just one part of a more complex query)

Regards.

Comment: I quite didnt get your question. Whats your desired output?

Comment: Thanks. My mistake, I have edited the post.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Thanks!! @a_horse_with_no_name, I did not know about that sentence. I have to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors(id) AS
   (SELECT id
       FROM register
       WHERE id NOT IN (2, 6)
         AND father_id IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT r.id
       FROM register r
            JOIN ancestors a
               ON r.father_id = a.id
       WHERE r.id NOT IN (2, 6)
   )
SELECT r.*
FROM ancestors
   NATURAL JOIN register r;

┌────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ id │ name │ father_id │
├────┼──────┼───────────┤
│  1 │ A    │           │
│  8 │ H    │         1 │
└────┴──────┴───────────┘
(2 rows)
```